# How can I cache the LearnDash quizzes on my server?

Tags: cache

I'm using the WP LearnDash module for providing my courses. I see sudden horrible lags particularly when using the quizzes. Most of the time they load in a couple of seconds. However, sometimes it can take > 30 seconds and it just kills the experience for some of the users. I need to improve their loading times.

The quizzes IMO should be static content. Each time the user answers a question and clicks next it makes a new call to the server to check (which is remarkably stupid IMO) but anyway it should be static I think.

Is there a way I could cache the quiz content on the server side somehow so as to speed up quiz loading times?

Comment: Probably, possibly, maybe :) What http server are you using? Apache, Nginx, etc. Apache, by default does have a cache module loaded and there maybe some tweaks available. Nginx is very good at caching too. All this is dependent on learndash passes headers, perhaps it asks to bypass caching.

Comment: It's an Apache server (Shared hosting).

Comment: Have you had a look at the "Cache-control" response header sent by the Apache server? That might give a clue. Also, there maybe an "X-Cache" or similar header being set, this value might identify something useful. If it says "Bypass" something is setting it to NOT cache it. This link might be useful https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/caching.html